# How to write negative loop in ruby like for(i=index; i >= 0; i --)

Tags: ruby, loops

How can I write a loop in Ruby that counts down, similar to the following C-style `for` loop?

```
for (i = 25; i >= 0; i--) { 
    print i;
}
```

Comment: note that your question should read `for (i = index; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: If you're new with ruby, why does your profile say you have 5 years of RoR experience?

Comment: Yeah mark :) , I was a php developer before

Comment: @MarkThomas unless ror_master edited his profile, there's nothing in it to indicate how his 5 years experience broke down across various platforms.

Comment: While that's technically true, it *is* listed first, and it's not like you would assume that 'ror_master' has little to no Ruby experience. It just seems misleading.

Comment: @dan  . you are right... !  I will make correction in my profile when get tym.thanks

Comment: @mark, I created account here to learn ruby ... my intension is not to misguide anybuddy...and its been only few month

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are many ways to perform a decrementing loop in Ruby:

**First way:**

```
for i in (10).downto(0)
  puts i
end
```

**Second way:**

```
(10).downto(0) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

**Third way:**

```
i=10;
until i<0
  puts i
  i-=1
end
```

Comment: 1st way contains extraneous parens, and is not very idiomatic. 2nd way also contains extraneous parens, has an unnecessary 'each', and has unnecessary quotes and variable interpolation. 3rd way is simply broken.

Comment: @MarkThomas: I think the extraneous parentheses are to make it seem less awkward to new Ruby users, like me. In Javascript, the same thing is possible, but you need to use two dots (the radix point and property accessor): `65536..toExponential()`. It's a somewhat awkward way of allowing property access, so I imagine that it is at least not very common to use or even know about in other languages where it is possible to directly access properties of a number using a dot.

Answer (score 30):

One way:

```
25.downto(0) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Comment: I guess you figured out ranges can't be used like this ;-)

Comment: That was someone else's answer, since deleted. It wouldn't have crossed my mind to use a range when this is precisely what `downto` is for.

Comment: Sorry about that then. I was amused by the answer, but failed to remember the name :-)

Comment: When I first typed it, I did have an 'each' though. A couple of seconds later I realized the each wasn't necessary and removed it.

Comment: Indeed - using an enumerator is unnecessary in this particular situation (but it's perfectly legal).

Answer (score 20):

`downto` is fine, but there is also the more generic `step`.

```
25.step(0, -1){|i| puts i}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
25.downto(0) { |i| puts i }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are working with a range already:

```
rng = 0..6
rng.reverse_each { |i| p i }
```

EDIT - more succinctly:

```
puts(rng.to_a.reverse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler one:

```
(0..25).reverse_each { |i| print i }
```

Answer (score 0):

Print reverse array elements:

```
nummarray = [3,4,7,3,6,8]

(numarray.length-1).downto(0){ |i| print numarray[i] }
```