# Decrement the array in ruby using for loop

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am new to ruby i was writing a code in which i required a array decrement [stackoverflow prob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926477/how-to-write-negative-loop-in-ruby-like-fori-index-i-0-i). I am trying to multiply the two numbers such that the result of the multiplication should be like the given format:

```
       325
    * 4405
  ---------
      1625
      000
    1300
   1300
  ---------
   1431625
```

This is my code.

```
a = gets.to_i
b = gets.to_i
e = b.to_s.split('')
d = a.to_s.split('')
for j in (e).downto(0)
  for i in (d).downto(0)
    puts w = ((e[i]).to_i)*((d[j]).to_i)
  end
end
```

For Input i am giving `a = 325` and `b = 4405`. 
But I am getting error

```
<main>': undefined method `downto' for ["4", "4", "0","5"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What do you try to do? Could you please also describe it in words?

Comment: I am sorry, i am trying to multiply the two numbers such that the result of the multiplication should be like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link.Its has explained types of iteration.  [iterator](http://www.dotnetperls.com/iterator)

Comment: Its helpful but still not able to fix my problem

Comment: If if didn't fix your problem, why did you accept the answer?