# Create array of n items based on integer value

Tags: ruby

Given I have an integer value of, e.g., `10`.

How can I create an array of 10 elements like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to populate an Array with a Range in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191329/correct-way-to-populate-an-array-with-a-range-in-ruby)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can just splat a range:

```
[*1..10]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Ruby 1.9 allows multiple splats, which is rather handy:

```
[*1..3, *?a..?c]
#=> [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: This is great, because I didn't realised before that: [*0..0] #=> [0] But, [*1..0] #=> []

Comment: @MichaelKohl - thank you - what does the question mark ? before the letters above signify?

Comment: They are character literals. `?c == 'c' #=> true`

Comment: @MichaelKohl looks like a rather foreign approach, I think I'd prefer to use single quotes for clarity as in `[*1..3, *'a'..'z']` but this is great for code golfing and I also didn't know that `?a == 'a'` (maybe I'm missing more?), thumbs up :D

Comment: It may look foreign, but it's one of the literals Ruby supports. Others you may not be aware of are rationals `1/3r #=> (1/3)` and complex numbers `1 + 5i #=> (1+5i)`

Comment: I know you wrote this 7 years ago, but this is pretty cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

yet another tricky way:

```
> Array.new(10) {|i| i+1 }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 10):

About comments with tricky methods:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm { |x|
  x.report('[*..] ') do
    [*1000000 .. 9999999]
  end  

  x.report('(..).to_a') do
    (1000000 .. 9999999).to_a
  end

  x.report('Array(..)') do
    Array(1000000 .. 9999999)
  end

  x.report('Array.new(n, &:next)') do
    Array.new(8999999, &:next)
  end

}
```

Be careful, this tricky method `Array.new(n, &:next)` is slower while three other basic methods are same.

```
                           user     system      total        real
[*..]                  0.734000   0.110000   0.844000 (  0.843753)
(..).to_a              0.703000   0.062000   0.765000 (  0.843752)
Array(..)              0.750000   0.016000   0.766000 (  0.859374)
Array.new(n, &:next)   1.250000   0.000000   1.250000 (  1.250002)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
def array_up_to(i)
    (1..i).to_a
end
```

Which allows you to:

```
 > array_up_to(10)
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
array= Array(0..10)
```

If you want to input, you can use this:

```
puts "Input:"
n=gets.to_i
array= Array(0..n)
puts array.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on of the most efficient way would be:

```
(1..10).to_a
```