# How to create array from 1 to n digit with single line of code in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need to create an array of 1 to n numbers with a single line of code in ruby.

I have tried it using while loop. But I'm sure there are other simpler way of doing this in ruby.

```
a = []
b = 1
while b < 100 do
  a << b
  b += 1 
end
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: Must be a dup. Anyhow you can do `[*1..10]` etc.

Comment: The exact question (even "1 to 10") was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173173/create-array-of-n-items-based-on-integer-value).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert a range into an array.

```
(1..n).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

another way
You can just splat a range:

```
[*1..n]
```

example

```
[*1..10]
=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### Or

```
a= Array(0..10)
puts a # => =>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Downvote. Stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173335/131160