# Rails - Convert number to array

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a number 5

How would I convert this to an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

The application here is I have an instance variable @pages and I want to create a pagination view.

Answer (score 3):

```
pages = 5
array_of_numbers = (1..pages).to_a
```

`(1..pages)` will give you a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) object and `to_a` will convert it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/times pointed me to a solution

`pages = 5
(1..pages).each { |n| puts n }`

Comment: You have a lot of other ways in [older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191329/correct-way-to-populate-an-array-with-a-range-in-ruby/6587096). I guess isn't necessary to create a new question for that.

Comment: This won't return an array. It will just print the nos.